# Creating an android gridview that spans multiple columns and rows based on position

Tags: android, gridview

I want to implement a grid layout that is capable of spanning multiple rows and columns based on position. Say suppose when the span count is 3. Item position zero, take two row spans and two column spans,item position one take two columns spans and one row span item position two, take one column span and one row span item position three, take one column span and one row span

Basically I want a view to span through various columns and rows depending upon its position.

I tried using GridLayoutManager of Recycle view using the setSpanSizeLookUp method, but it spans a view either horizontally or vertically.

I found out that the twowayview can be used to span multiple columns and rows but I am not sure how to implement that in my project since its an extensive library(having problems setting it up in android studio).

Can anyone suggest best approach?

Answer (score 1):

In researching your question, I learned something new: I happened to look at GridLayoutManager for RecyclerView and I noticed that you can set a custom SpanSizeLookup. Now a "span" is just a column if you're scrolling vertically and a row if you're scrolling horizontally. So the SpanSizeLookup allows you to specify for example, item 0 takes 2 columns, item 1 takes 1 column, etc.

It turns out that if you use RecyclerView with a GridLayoutManager the solution is easy-peasy:

```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Create a grid layout with two columns
    GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);

    // Create a custom SpanSizeLookup where the first item spans both 
 columns
    layoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new 
 GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
        @Override
        public int getSpanSize(int position) {
            return position == 0 ? 2 : 1;
        }
    });

    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)  
  findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new MyGridAdapter());
   }
```

A note about the adapter: RecyclerView.Adapter is not compatible with ListAdapter. You need to extend your adapter from RecyclerView.Adapter and make the appropriate changes.

Here is the adapter I created for my test project:

```
    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ImageView mImageView;
    TextView mTextView;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        mTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    }
   }

    public static class MyGridAdapter extends     
    RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder> {

    private int[] mDrawables;

    public MyGridAdapter() {
        this.mDrawables = new int[] {
                R.drawable.images_01,
                R.drawable.images_02,
                .
                .
                .
        };
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDrawables.length;
    }

      @Override
      public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int   
        viewType) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) 
   parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_grid_item, parent,  
       false);
        MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
        // set up any onClickListener you need on the view here
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.mImageView.setImageResource(mDrawables[position]);
        holder.mTextView.setText("Image " + position);
    }
   }






  Here xml of Activity


     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context="com.syneotek.gridlayoutmanagerdemo.Demo2">


 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview">

 </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

And here is xml of Grid item_list

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 >


  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/grid_item_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" >
  </ImageView>

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Munaf Patel"/>

 </LinearLayout>


    Best of Luck.
```